# Comparison of JS frameworks in reference to themes and solutions in dojo

Tags: javascript, frameworks, dojo, themes, generator

Hey guys,
I was creating a simple website using dojo for all kind of stuff like effects, ajax ... 
At the beginning I really liked it but now I run into a lot of trouble when it comes to the design part. My site is using some self written css. So everytime I write something in Dojo like an uploader or contact form I have to add a lot of new styles cause the js framework generates a lot of code for each object. Because I only have a finite amout of time I do not like this ... so I searched for a solution and found some templates wich can be used to create a nice layout. Unfortunately there are only a small amount (4) of templates available and all of them do not fit because of my existing design. So now finally the questions:

1) Is there something like a theme-generator for dojo templates?
2) Can I do something else than changing hundreds lines of css-code to make the design good looking on my site?
3) Are there alternatives? Like other JS frameworks where this is easier to handle?

Currently my existing js files are not that big (200-300 lines) so it would be possible to switch to an other framework - but before I would like to know weather this will have an positive impact on my site. :)

I hope you can help me out! 
Thanks in advance,

Sylvus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a theme generator for Dojo. However, if you check out the Claro theme in Dojo 1.6, it's built using Less, and by doing some variable changes, you may be able to easily create a custom theme.

Dijit, Dojo's UI system, is built to some pretty high standards in terms of support for accessibility and internationalization and such, and part of that means that the markup it uses is fairly complex at times. It does make them a bit more difficult to style, but it's definitely possible to build up some custom look and feel.

Alternatively, if you wanted to create some custom UI elements, you can use the dijit._Widget and dijit._Templated pieces to build up your own custom widgets, which would give you full control over final markup and classes, making it easier to style, while still getting at least some level of functionality similar to what Dijit natively provides. Check out http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/writingWidgets.html for more details on writing your own custom widgets.

There are plenty of other JS UI libraries, like jQuery UI, or Mocha for MooTools, but from past experience, those can prove to take some effort to create custom styles for as well. The jQuery UI ThemeRoller is an interesting tool that I've used to create a custom theme for a simple site at one point, though going fully custom still took effort.